# Get current route and add param to it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the below route url in an MVC razor view

```
@Url.RouteUrl(new { lang = "EN"})
```

**I want to have it match the default mapped route for the current view and add the querystring param on the end**

I only have the default mapped route for controller actions in my global.asax.cs file.

I recently installed ELMAH and now the first match is

```
/elmah?lang=EN
```

I have tried seeing what the below gets me

```
@Url.RouteUrl(Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.Values)
```

and I end up with

```
/elmah?Count={number of errors here}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try it with `@Url.RouteUrl(Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values)` so with only one `Values`.

Comment: Thanks that at least is getting me the current URL, whats the appropriate way to add the new parameter on to it.. it wouldn't let me call .Add("lang", "EN") because that no longer returns the relevant route dictionary that RouteUrl expects. Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: You can do it with two steps and with the help of a temp variable. Like this: `@{ var myRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values); myRouteValues.Add("lang", "EN"); } @Url.RouteUrl(myRouteValues)`

Comment: Yea I was hoping not to have to do that but if thats the appropriate way then so be it :) You should add it as an answer so I can mark it as such. Thanks

Comment: No, I don't think that this is the appropriate way to solve this. That is why I posted it as a comment. But currently I don't know any better solution but maybe somebody will post a more elegant answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question for @nemesv who answered it as best as possible at the time in the comments

> You can do it with two steps and with the help of a temp variable.
>   Like this:

```
@{ 
    var myRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(
        Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values
    );
    myRouteValues.Add("lang", "EN"); 
} 

@Url.RouteUrl(myRouteValues)
```

this is only so I can close this.